# r - rpivotTable bug: The value on the table is not the same with the value on bar plot

Tags: r, pivot-table, rpivottable

I found an issue with the package rpivotTable, see an example blow:

```
>USD<-c(-14567,212091,-345678,456172)
>KNTD<-c(-231234,111323,-3145670,5012344)
>category<-c("A","B","C","D")
>item<-c("E","F","G","H")
>table<-data.frame(category, item, USD, KNTD)
>table
     category item     USD     KNTD
 1        A    E    -14567  -231234
 2        B    F    212091   111323
 3        C    G   -345678 -3145670
 4        D    H    456172  5012344
>rpivotTable(table)
```

The values are correct in the Table.(Picture1)
[image: Pic1]

However, in picture 2, the value of A shows "-14,600."
[image: Pic2]

in picture 3, the value of C shows "-346,000.", both A and C are not correct 
and they are negative values. I'm wondering if it's a bug or did I wrongly missed something. Thanks.
[image: Pic3]

Comment: Could it be a rounding problem?

Comment: @akrun: Maybe, but can you explain more? All of the values are integers.

Comment: You may need to check the function code to see whether it does such sort of things.  I don't have the package installed.  Also, big integers may get converted to double and then the rounding happens.

Comment: @akrun: Thanks, and the rounding only happens on negative values. No rounding on positive values.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay ;). I'm the creator of the package (on top of the marvellous work of the creator of pivottable.JS). Thanks for using rpivotTable.  the problem you report appear like a c3 bug.  I reported here https://github.com/nicolaskruchten/pivottable/issues/692

Comment: And I'm the creator of the underlying PivotTable.js library ... I've fixed the bug there so hopefully we can get the fix upstreamed soon :)

Comment: Thanks, so there will be a new version release?